# Trouble saving from post data via form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

When I try to run the create method below with a list of attributes from a form, it fails with this error, even though the user is definitely included:

> null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

I tried adding a `UserSignupInfo` record via the shell using `create()` with the same result.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
class UserSignupInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    ...

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **attributes):
        signup_attributes = {}
        for key in attributes:
            if key in cls.fields:
                signup_attributes[key] = attributes[key]

        signup_info = cls(**signup_attributes)
        signup_info.save()
        return signup_info
```

Comment: Looks like this is because of a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model.

Comment: Yes, user is an FK.  Shouldn't assigning user=<User: some user> work here?

Comment: what is the motivation for overriding `create()` method?

Comment: To filter irrelevant data that may come in from a form.

Comment: Ok, sounds like a [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) task..

Comment: Ok, that's fair.  Why does it fail here, though?  Shouldn't create be able to accept fields from the model?

Comment: We can't tell without knowing what `cls.fields` is, or seeing what is in `attributes`. As alecxe says though, this should be done via a ModelForm (you won't even need to extend the validation, as all you're doing is what is done by default in a ModelForm anyway).